# Hadoop jobtracker HA with version 1.1.2

Tags: hadoop

Is it possible to configure hadoop jobtracker High Availability using the community hadoop distribution of version 1.1.2?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get a real HA solution (except of switching distribution to MapR), but with help of job completion persistance you can achieve some sort of. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-3245 This solution can help JT tolerate restarts.